# After executing a trigger unable to insert a new data into the table anyone

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE
AFTER INSERT 
ON EMPLOYEE_MASTER

FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
INSERT INTO TIMELINE
(tl_date,tl_name)
values(new.em_first_name, SYSDATE());
end;
```

Comment: but I am getting error

Comment: Is there anything to insert extra